# hostname not appearing in file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do I put the hostname of a server into the export-csv filename?

I have tried the below and the csv is created but the name is empty?

If I try WITHOUT the hostname the filename is filled in...obviously without the hostname though.

```
$Hostname = gc env:computername
$Filename = "{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}" -f (Get-Date)

$files | Export-CSV $export\$Hostname_$Filename_filelist.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're interpolating variables into strings, it can help to be a little more explicit. Give this a try:

```
$files | Export-CSV "$($export)\$($Hostname)_$($Filename)_filelist.csv" -NoTypeInfo
```

It should work more predictably, and as a side benefit the variables will pop out to your eyes a bit easier when you go back to look at the code later!

Even when you don't strictly need the parentheses, I find that sometimes it helps to ensure that you and the Powershell interpreter have the same idea about what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is how I would approach it too.  There's also no point populating a variable with the hostname, just call it directly: "$($export)\$($env:computername)_$($Filename)_filelist.csv" In addition "$($export)\$($env:computername)_$("{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}" -f (Get-Date))_filelist.csv" also works fine but is possibly less readable!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$files | Export-Csv ("${env:COMPUTERNAME}_{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)) -NoType
```